# join multiple fields to one table

Tags: select, mysql, join, multiple-columns

I have 2 tables (there are more but un related to question) `optionValue` and `productStock`

I want to get the option names from the optionValue table for each option1, option2, option3 (the query below will should help to make more sense)

below is my attempt, the current query it only works if all options are set but is returns null if any option is not set:

> ```
>     SELECT s.option1, n1.name s.optionName1, 
>            s.option2, n2.name s.optionName2,
>            s.option3, n3.name s.optionName3
>     FROM productStock as s 
>     INNER JOIN optionValue n1 on s.option1 = v1.optionValueID
>     INNER JOIN optionValue n2 on s.option2 = v2.optionValueID
>     INNER JOIN optionValue n3 on s.option3 = v3.optionValueID
>     WHERE s.productStockID = 1
> ```

I understand why it doesn't work because when the option is `null` ther is no matches to the `optionValue` table but im not sure how to fix it (if it is fixable)

I read in a couple of places about using IN or COALESCE but I don't understand how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really need first it to correct your database design. Anytime you have fields like this:
s.option1,s.option2, s.option3

Then what you really need is a child table to store the information. What happens when you need 6 options or 25?  This is a very bad database design and will cause no end of problems incuding the inefficent query you now have to write. This is a cancer at the heart of your system and needs to be fixed before anything else is done.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like some of your syntax is a little incorrect.

Apart from that you want `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

[Visual explanation of SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).